TypeError: (0 , vue_yandex_maps__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.createYmapPlugin) is not a function
Установил vue-yandex-map, выдает ошибку что не поддерживается (imported as 'createYmapPlugin') was not found

вот ошибка:
ERROR
(0 , vue_yandex_maps__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.createYmapPlugin) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , vue_yandex_maps__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.createYmapPlugin) is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:26:287)
    at ./src/main.js (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:107:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:514:32)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1630:109
    at __webpack_require__.O (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:556:23)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1631:53
    at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1633:12
ERROR
Script error.
    at handleError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js:299:58)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js:318:7)


вот main.js:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { createYmapPlugin } from 'vue-yandex-maps'

library.add(fas, far, fab)

const settings = {
    apiKey: 'key',
    lang: 'ru_RU',
    coordorder: 'latlong',
    debug: false,
    version: '2.1',
}

createApp(App).component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon).mount('#app').use(createYmapPlugin(settings))


вот компонент карты:
<template>
  <div class="map-container">
    <yandex-map :settings="settings" :coords="[55.751574, 37.573856]" zoom="10">
      <ymap-marker :coords="[55.751574, 37.573856]"></ymap-marker>
    </yandex-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { YandexMap, YmapMarker } from 'vue-yandex-maps';

</script>

